# Rewrite URL in php using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

need to change the `URL` as per `Title` of the page.I have a URL like `http://yourdomain.com/showBest.html?id=42` & I need to make it as `http://yourdomain.com/how-to-feel-cosmic-energy.html` here its how to feel cosmic energy is `Title` of the page. All can say, i need to connect the web URl from `Title` of the page using `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/, following is a less optimal way to write it. However this requires the least work. In your .htaccess, you use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ showBest.html?id=$2
```

This converts `how-to-feel-cosmic-energy/12.html` to `showBest.html?id=12`.

And you don't have to change the PHP code. The simplification is because this rule cheats by including both the page title and the id. Therefore, the rewrite rule doesn't have to look in a database.

---

The better way is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ showBest.html?title=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ showBest.html?title=$1
```

This converts `how-to-feel-cosmic-energy.html` to `showBest.html?title=how-to-feel-cosmic-energy`.

However, with this method, you have to change your PHP. So instead of searching for record by id, you have to search by title.

eg. change

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = " + mysql_escape_string($id))
```

to

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title = '"
            + mysql_escape_string($title) + "'")
```

or similar (depending on your exact PHP code).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a framework for doing this, you're going to either have to write scripts to take page titles and turn them into page ID's (using a lookup in a database or whatever), or use a [RewriteMap to create a title->id mapping](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).

This isn't a matter of a simple few rewrite rules.